# hibernate validation not triggering on persist?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

Read through this article

https://thorben-janssen.com/automatically-validate-entities-with-hibernate-validator/#Automatic_Validation_upon_Lifecycle_Events

has this quote "The validation gets automatically executed when Hibernate, or any other JPA implementation, triggers a pre-persist, pre-update or pre-remove lifecycle events"

so, I was expecting failures in persist.  I added hibernate-validator BUT did NOT add the el stuff (**and it didn't seem to fail without it**...not sure why it needs el).

***Is there a running simple github example somewhere*** I can compare with to track this issue down?

versions:

- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.10.Final
- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.3.Final
- org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b09

I simply added a bunch of annotations like so from javax.validation.constraints. and expected entityManager.persist to fail but it worked and inserted the bean in the database.

```
@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String phone;
@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String name;
@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String firstName;
```

I use a class

```
public class DbSettingsInMemory implements PersistenceUnitInfo
```

of

```
public class DbSettingsInProd implements PersistenceUnitInfo
```

instead of a persistence.xml as well.  Not sure if that really matters.  We do this to avoid the classpath issues of finding persistence.xml that comes up in IDE's and such and it's been way smoother experience.  Here is our full file in case this is causing it to not work

```
public class DbSettingsInMemory implements PersistenceUnitInfo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbSettingsInMemory.class);
    
    private Properties properties = new Properties();

    private HikariDataSource dataSource;
    
    @Inject
    public DbSettingsInMemory(MeterRegistry metrics) {
        //<!-- property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" /-->
        //properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy");
        //properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:log4jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        //properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "sa");
        //properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");
        
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion", "true");
        //properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider");
        
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy");
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:log4jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        config.setUsername("sa");
        config.setPassword("");
        config.setMetricRegistry(metrics);
         
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
        return "inmemory";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceProviderClassName() {
        return "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider";
    }

    @Override
    public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getJtaDataSource() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getNonJtaDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * root of where to scan from.  MAKE this a very small scope so scanning is very very quick
     */
    @Override
    public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
        String name = DbSettingsInMemory.class.getSimpleName() + ".class";
        URL url = DbSettingsInMemory.class.getResource(name);
        String file = url.getFile();
        int length = file.length() - name.length(); 
        String root = file.substring(0, length);
        try {
            URL rootUrl = new URL(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), root);
            log.info("RootURL for scanning="+rootUrl);
            return rootUrl;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bug", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean excludeUnlistedClasses() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
        return SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
        return ValidationMode.NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.  webpieces needs to pass in Development Classloader");
    }

    @Override
    public void addTransformer(ClassTransformer transformer) {
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
        return null;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

EDIT:
I thought of something else to add to at least make sure validation was working just before the persist/flush is called like so

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDbo>> list = validator.validate(entity);
    
    log.info("list="+list);
    
    Em.get().persist(entity);
    Em.get().flush();
```

I correctly see 4 violations in the list but persist and flush succeeds :(.

From the debugger...

[image]

Digging into hibernate code, I find a BeanValidationEventListener.java but it seems that is only wired in via dependency injection ??  not quite sure but it is not wired in for some reason to hibernate but needs to be somehow.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Are you using spring-boot and if so what version? What are Validation related dependencies you declared?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai nope, using just hibernate in an app. 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.10.Final', 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.5.Final',and 'org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b09',

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you to set `javax.persistence.validation.mode` to `callback` in the properties of your EMF.

This forces the Bean Validation integration and might give you a proper error message. Otherwise if Bean Validation fails to initialize, you don't have any error message.

That being said, there's a good chance it won't solve your issue. How do you initialize your `SessionFactoryImpl`?

Because if you don't have CDI or Spring integration, you have to manually hook up Hibernate ORM and Hibernate Validator.

A good entry point is SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder#applyValidatorFactory().

Comment: I figured it out finally and posted an answer @GuillaumeSmet .  I upvoted your answer for trying though as I had tried that and forgot to edit my post once I found that gem out.  thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  It turns out in the above file, there is this method that killed it EVEN after I set properties to callback or auto or ddl or even auto, ddl.

```
@Override
public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
    return ValidationMode.NONE;
}
```

In the hibernate docs, it says you can do callback, ddl so you get two types but I guess doing a PU only allows one type :(.